# Downloading from ubuntu terminal

Tags: php, ubuntu, curl, ubuntu-12.04, composer-php

I have a problem that some stuff don't get downloaded from the terminal , though that I tested the connection by `sudo apt-get update` and it worked but something like `curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php`

gives me this error : Download failed: file_get_contents(https://getcomposer.org/composer.phar): failed to open stream: Connection timed out

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what you want to download but for downloading any file from terminal it can help you.

```
wget http://www.site_name.com/path/to/filename.extention
```

For Example of one Image :-

```
wget http://www.hdpaperz.com/wp-content/gallery/wallpaper_wallpaper_03/cool-wodden-wall-graffiti-1080p-hd-wallpaper.jpg
```